# Disable the whole Context Menu

Tags: wpf, contextmenu

I know there is a way to block or now show context menu by using `ContextMenuOpening` event.

But I still want to show the context menu, just disable everything in it, is there a way to do it?

How can I disable all the menu item at a same time?

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemDataTemplate">
    <Grid Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="New" Click="New_Click" />
                <Separator />
                <MenuItem Header="Duplicate" Click="Duplicate_Click"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Delete" Click="Delete_Click"  />
                <MenuItem Header="Rename" Click="Rename_Click" />
                <Separator />
                <MenuItem Header="Export..." Click="Export_Click" />
                <MenuItem Header="Print..."
                          Command="ApplicationCommands.Print"
                          InputGestureText="" />
                <Separator />
                <MenuItem Header="Properties" Click="Properties_Click" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </Grid.ContextMenu>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Margin="0,0,10,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Background="Transparent"
                    IsHitTestVisible="False">    
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>    
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solve my question.

Still use `ContextMenuOpening` event. Use a loop.

This why can help me disable certain context menu item in code, but not in `XAML`.

```
private void SetContextMenuItemsEnableStatus(object sender)
{
    FrameworkElement element = sender as FrameworkElement;
    if (element == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    ContextMenu contextMenu = element.ContextMenu;          
    if (contextMenu == null)
        return;
    //Use this way.
    //You can disable every item or certain item in context menu.
    foreach (Control item in contextMenu.Items)
    {
        item.IsEnabled = false;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 7):

```
<Style x:Key="z3r0_Style_TextBox_Default" BasedOn="{x:Null}"
    TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11"/>
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource z3r0_SolidColorBrush_DarkerGray}"/>
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}"/>
<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Consolas"/>
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource z3r0_SolidColorBrush_Green}"/>
<Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
<Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="10"/>
<Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
<Setter Property="ContextMenu">                
    <Setter.Value>
        <ContextMenu IsEnabled="False" Visibility="Hidden">
        </ContextMenu>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

For me, setting `IsEnabled` to False still caused a small empty context menu to be visible. After changing its visibility attribute, it was truly disabled.

Answer (score 6):

`IsEnabled = false` on the `ContextMenu`?

**Edit:** As there appear to be closing problems when doing this i would suggest a container style:

```
<ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
        </Style>
    </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
    <MenuItem Header="Test"/>
</ContextMenu>
```

Of course the actual value can be bound as well but in the container style the context is the individual item, so to bind to the parent context a [`RelativeSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.aspx) binding is necessary (unless the data object also has a connection to the parent).

Comment: dude it is in datatemplate, if just put IsEnabled = false, how can I enable it when I need it? one Item can have different context menu, depends on the situation.

Comment: HB, I have the same problem, I tried this (in XAML and I bound the IsEnabled property to a flag in my ModelView), but now my context menu wont disappear after its opened.

Comment: @tianxu0836: I have no idea why i did not get what you were saying the first time around. Anyway, you can use a [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) expression instead of the `false`-literal. Though bindings in `ContextMenus` can be tricky...

Comment: Put a DataTrigger in the Style and there you are.
`            <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle >
                <Style TargetType="MenuItem" >
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RulesEditing}"
                                     Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" 
                                    Value="False" />
                        </DataTrigger>  
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>`

Answer (score 2):

The entire context menu can be disabled at the root of the `ContextMenu` by setting the [`IsEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu_properties.aspx) property to false; there is no need to loop through each menu item in code.

```
<ContextMenu IsEnabled="False">
```

Or

```
<ContextMenu IsEnabled={Binding Path=SomeModelBooleanProperty}">
```

This will enable the context menu to be viewed, but all items will be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I used `ContextMenu="{x:Null}"` to disable the Context Menu in a TextBox.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solve my question.

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="TreeViewEmptyContextMenu" Width="0" Height="0"/>
```